# php array_multisort how to but the SORT_ASC and SORT_DESC into variables

Tags: php, sorting, variables, array-multisort

Hi im interested to let my query tell my web app how to sort an array.

Everything is working fine, but i can't figure out a clever way to have the URL (page.php?order=asc) grab that query with:

```
$order = $_GET['order'];
```

and put it into:

```
array_multisort($sort['name'], SORT_ASC, $array);
```

this doesnt seem to work:

```
$test = SORT_ASC;
array_multisort($sort['name'], $test, $array);
```

Had a hard time googling for this, so hopefully some smart brain here can help me out :)
thank you

Comment: yes it is, sorry about that. Im mainly interested to know how to store the SORT_ASC and SORT_DESC in a variable

Comment: Sorry! It was me, I misunderstood the question =), But I guess I was surpised because you're defining a Constant, that's already a Constant - so why do you need it to be.. another Constant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second code example using `$test` should work, I use that all the time. Here is how to use the `asc` from `$_GET['order']`:

```
$order = constant('SORT_' . strtoupper($_GET['order']));
array_multisort($sort['name'], $order, $array);
```

Comment: Thank you!! thats what i needed, so just so that i understand too, when i want to stare a constant value in a variable, i have to use constant()? and SORT_ASC is a constant?

Comment: Actually your second code example using `$test` should work.  I use that all the time.  I was just showing how to use the `asc` from the get var.